# Is there an equivalent of Apex's 'system.debug' in Java?

Tags: java, apex

I recently started coding with Apex and have been utilizing the 'system.debug()' method. It helps me keep track of variables in my code by printing the variable in the 'debug log'. Now I am studying Java, and I was wondering if an equivalent method exists in Java. I would like to see what my variables are in certain parts of my code.

Comment: Use an IDE debugger (Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, etc). MUCH easier than inserting debug statements.

Comment: I just read a little bit about Apex `system.debug` and it seems like it is merely a logging utility. Java comes with a logging utility class as well (`Logger.class`). Java's `System` class contains an output stream that will allow you to dump printouts to the console. That said, Jim Garrison is correct. Instead of using these utilities for debugging, you should consider using a debugger or profiling tool. I have used YourKit in the past and it is pretty good for finding hot spots and bottlenecks in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), like `System.out` to call `print` or `println` in order to display your debug. You can also [redirect](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-write-console-output-to-text-file-in-java/) `System.out` to file using `setOut`.

However, if you use an IDE and a debugger, you can create a breakpoint to the line that you wish to debug and let a debugger run until it reaches your line.